# Rust free unwrap for vec of newtypes

Tags: rust, newtype

If I have the following program:

```
struct Foo {
    a: usize,
    b: usize,
}

struct Bar(Foo);

fn unwrap_bars(bars: Vec<Bar>) -> Vec<Foo> {
  bars.into_iter().map(|b| b.0).collect()
}
```

Will `unwrap_bars` be compiled to an identity function? If it is not compiled to an identity function then how could I write `unwrap_bars` so that I keep the newtype abstraction while allowing free unwrapping of a collection of `Bar`s?

I assume that a newtype wrapper like `Bar` compiles directly to `Foo` without adding any extra memory indirection.

Comment: [I don't think but I just try to read mir for the first time](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=69993f69b0214dbe71031af5a2ba018f&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: @Stargateur I was looking at the assembly, rather than MIR, and it surprisingly looked like it did. I know that `clang` has learned to optimize away some operations on C++'s `std::vector` related to memory allocation, this would be implemented in LLVM, and Rust could benefit from it as well. But the code was quite inlined, so I might just have missed something. In any case, I would certainly not rely on it being an no-op.

Answer (score 3):

No, I doubt your function would result in an identity function(I looked at the generated assembly and there was definitely an allocation). This would though:

```
fn unwrap_bars(mut bars : Vec<Bar>) -> Vec<Foo> {
    unsafe {
        let ptr = bars.as_mut_ptr() as *mut Foo;
        let len = bars.len();
        let cap = bars.capacity();
        std::mem::forget(bars);     // to prevent destructor being called
        Vec::from_raw_parts(ptr, len, cap)
    }
}
```